# Scroll mouse down triggers a mapping

Tags: key-bindings

Usually I know how to debug mapping. But I am not sure about this.
When I do scroll down using the mouse, it enters insert mode and adds a line.
I believe it is a bad mapping that is triggered (on windows).

It happens after I did `set eventignore=all` .
It doesn't happen on `-u NONE`.
I tried to look at all my mappings, there are 1600 lines of it, and I couldn't find anything suspicious.
I tried profiling , too much lines (even after eventignore?!) .

`C-v` returned `\]1` (esc is not mapped)

Any ideas?

(It only happens on my TUI, that is goneovim, but not on -u NONE)

Comment: A profiling that supports mappings could be a good idea...

Comment: Best is to disable parts of your config until you can narrow it down... Disable all plugins, or leave only plugins and disable the rest, then go on halving the config every time. Also note that ESC is `Ctrl+[` and it seems what you're seeing is `Ctrl+]`. You can try `:map` then `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+]` (shows as `^]`) to see if you have any mappings starting with that symbol...